# Bluetooth mouse Logitech M555b not recognized on a Macbook Pro 8.2

Tags: 12.04, mouse, bluetooth, macbook, logitech

I just bought a Logitech M555b Bluetooth mouse today.
My computer (a Macbook Pro 8,2) has a bluetooth connection, and it works perfectly fine on Mac OSX (I set up a new device, click the connect button on the mouse, and voilà, done in 5 seconds).

I cannot get it to work on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I follow the same steps as on Mac OSX under Ubuntu 12.04, Sometimes I will see the mouse name appearing for 1 second on the screen, and if I'm fast enough to click on "Continue", I will have a message telling me the pairing with my mouse failed.

Here are the steps I follow:

1. Turn off Bluetooth on Ubuntu
2. Turn Bluetooth on.
3. Bluetooth icon > Set up new device...
4. Turn on the mouse, and press the Connect button.
5. Press "Continue" on the Bluetooth New Device Setup screen
6. I see the mouse name for one second, but then it disappear.
7. Click on PIN options... to select '0000'.
8. ... nothing, Ubuntu won't see anything.

In the /var/log/syslog, I have the following information:

```
May 27 23:26:16 Trane bluetoothd[896]: HCI dev 0 down
May 27 23:26:16 Trane bluetoothd[896]: Adapter /org/bluez/896/hci0 has been disabled
May 27 23:26:58 Trane bluetoothd[896]: HCI dev 0 up
May 27 23:26:58 Trane bluetoothd[896]: Adapter /org/bluez/896/hci0 has been enabled
May 27 23:26:58 Trane bluetoothd[896]: Inquiry Cancel Failed with status 0x12
May 27 23:28:26 Trane bluetoothd[896]: Refusing input device connect: No such file or directory (2)
May 27 23:28:26 Trane bluetoothd[896]: Refusing connection from 00:1F:20:24:15:3D: setup in progress
May 27 23:28:26 Trane bluetoothd[896]: Discovery session 0x7f3409ab5b70 with :1.84 activated
```

I tried for an hour, I restarted my computer, re-paired the mouse on Mac OSX, etc.

Sometimes when I restart the computer, I have a dialog box showing up saying that the mouse M555b wants to access some resources or something, if I click "Grant", or even if I tick "always grant access", nothing happens...

How can I get the Bluetooth to work properly? Help!

Answer (score 1):

It is known issue. Please read https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/774854 and mark that you are affected by this bug or write a comment.
I make it work after many trial-and-error attempts (as you wrote above).